# Apply str.lower to Pandas via list Comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I have a dataframe df of the form:

```
    animal    fruit
0    "Dog"    "Apple"
1    "Cat"    "Banana"
2    "Rat"    "Grape"
```

I want to apply str.lower() to all columns (but not headers).

This Works:

```
for i in df:
    df[i] = df[i].str.lower()
```

How can I write this as a list comphrension?

I tried:

```
df[i] = [df[i].str.lower() for i in df]
```

But this does not work and I get a:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not instancemethod
```

What must I change within the list comprehension for this to work?

Secondly, is there a more "Pandas-onicy" way of doing this in general, perhaps using the pandas.apply() function?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output from list comprehension is list of `Series`. So need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) `list`:

```
L = [df[i].str.lower() for i in df]
print (L)
[0    dog
1    cat
2    rat
Name: animal, dtype: object, 0     apple
1    banana
2     grape
Name: fruit, dtype: object]

df1 = pd.concat(L, axis=1)
print (df1)
  animal   fruit
0    dog   apple
1    cat  banana
2    rat   grape
```

---

Solution with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()))
  animal   fruit
0    dog   apple
1    cat  banana
2    rat   grape
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.concat([df]*1000, axis=1)
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
#[3000 rows x 2000 columns]
print (df)

In [89]: %timeit (pd.concat([df[i].str.lower() for i in df], axis=1))
1 loop, best of 3: 2.3 s per loop

In [90]: %timeit (df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()))
1 loop, best of 3: 2.63 s per loop

In [91]: %timeit (df.stack().str.lower().unstack())
1 loop, best of 3: 5.04 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, so the **concat** would be required doing any list comprehension in this way on a pandas d frame?

Comment: If need apply function working with `Series` like `str.lower()` then need concat method with list comprehension, which is fastest.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) so that it makes a single column, then call [`str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html#pandas.Series.str.lower), and then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to restore the columns back:

```
In [74]:
df = df.stack().str.lower().unstack()
df

Out[74]:
  animal   fruit
0    dog   apple
1    cat  banana
2    rat   grape
```

Comment: Thank you for your help - there are many of these functions to learn.